# Rules for using multi-indices

Tags: combinatorics, notation, index-notation

I've only encountered multi-index notation in the context of the multinomial theorem. There, the notation is used like this: $(k_1 + k_2 +...+k_m) = n, \ k_i \in \Bbb N_{\ge 0}^n$, iterate over every permutation of the summation.

So basically:
$$\sum_{(k_1 + k_2 + k_3) = 2} k = (1+1+0)+(1+0+1) + (0+1+1) +(2+0+0)+(0+2+0)+(0+0+2)$$

Is this true, or are there other rules?

Comment: It is true that the number of permutations is $6$, for $n=2$ and $m=3$. But your notation on the LHS is not right.

Comment: @callculus42 How come?

Comment: How come what? What do you mean?

Comment: In case there is any confusion, there is no need to say "iterate over every permutation of the summation".  We are simply taking all $m$-tuples of nonnegative integers satisfying $k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_m = n$, which automatically includes all permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The left-hand has to be written somewhat differently. We can write
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 2}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}} \left(k_1+k_2+k_3\right) &= (1+1+0)+(1+0+1) + (0+1+1)\\
> &\qquad+(2+0+0)+(0+2+0)+(0+0+2)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

On the other hand OPs left-hand expression can be written as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 2}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}k
&=k\sum_{{k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = 2}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}1\tag{2}\\
&=6k\tag{3}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we note that $k$ is a constant which does not depend on any of the indices $k_1,k_2,k_3$. We can therefore factor out $k$ leaving a term $1$ within the scope of the sum.
- In (3) we recall that the index range specifies $6$ valid triples $(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ with $k_1+k_2+k_3=2$. This is explicitly shown at the right-hand side of (1). Since there are $6$ valid terms, we can simplify the sum to $6$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the sigma functions at the bottom.

Comment: @user110391: I've added some details which might be helpful.

Comment: When one puts a $k$ in front of the sigma function with the multi-index notation, does that mean one is to multiply the individual sums by $k$? In this case, that would yield $12k$, wouldn't it? Since the individual sums all add up to $2$ respectively, and multiplied by $k$, that's six terms of $2k$, which equal to $12k$. This probably incorrect process applied to the RHS also gives $12k$. I hope this comment shows where my misunderstanding comes from. I haven't really encountered sigma functions where the index (or multi-indices) below it doesn't show up in front of the sigma.

Comment: @user110391: We have to differentiate between *constraints* of the indices and *terms* to add up which are in the scope of the sum. The expression $k_1+k_2+k_3=2$ is a *constraint* for the terms which are to add up. Here we have as term within the scope of the sum just the constant $1$. The constraints on the other hand specify $6$ triples as explicitly written out in (1). This means we have just $6$ times a term to add up and this terms is always the constant $1$.

Comment: @user110391: In order to avoid misunderstandings. In (1) we see that we have $6$ valid triples. The constraints are given by the $6$ triples $(1,1,0),(1.0,1),(0,1,1),(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2)$, since these are precisely the triples which fulfill: $k_1+k_2+k_3=2$.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly: $$\displaystyle \sum_{{(k_1 + k_2 +... k_n) = x} \atop {k_i \in \Bbb N_{\ge 0}}} k = P_n(x) \times k$$ where the parts in the partition $\ge 0$.

Comment: @user110391: Yes, this is correct, if $P_n(x)$ denotes the number of valid partitions.